# How to make a space for banner

Tags: java, android, facebook-audience-network, banner-ads

The layout is simple, One WebView and a Banner(AD).

I wrote an XML like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's a code to create a banner runtime.

```
// This code is copied & pasted from AudienceNetwork's guide page
adView = new AdView(this, "PLACEMENT_ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
adContainer.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd();
```

This code won't work, the banner is displayed outside of the screen.
So, what I looking for is `android:layout_height="match_parent - 50dp"` just like `calc` in CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such option of doing `android:layout_height="match_parent - 50dp"` in Android.

For integrating the Facebook audience network, you need to create an xml first with the `banner_container`. You can consider using a different layout structure like the following, using a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/banner_container" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but AudienceNetwork seems that they don't have direct XML layout. The documentation only describes dynamic(java) way.

Comment: Can you please provide the link? There should be an xml layout setting.

Comment: Sure, I prefer xml if possible.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-banners

Comment: Great to know that I could help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go with your existing layout just need to add a LinearLayout below Webview. Don't forgot to add android:layout_weight="1" in Webview

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:orientation="vertical">
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"></WebView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" />
```

then use your existing code

```
adView = new AdView(this, "PLACEMENT_ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
adContainer.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd();
```